# Get progression bar into PyQGIS 3 standalone script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, algorithm, standalone, progress

When I run a treatment inside QGIS with Processing toolbox (native algorithms) I get a progression bar :

[image]

Is there a way to use this percentage inside a standalone PyQGIS script? I searched in the description of `processing.run()` but it seems nothing is linking to this progression bar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - processing.run accepts a "feedback" argument, which must be an instance of a QgsProcessingFeedback subclass.

If you construct your own feedback object to pass to this function, you can connect to the progressChanged signal and handle progress reports:

```
def progress_changed(progress):
    print(progress)

f = QgsProcessingFeedback()
f.progressChanged.connect(progress_changed)
processing.run(...., feedback=f)
```