# Displaying progress bar when using QGIS processing tool

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm building a `QGIS` plugin and I want to improve the user interface. I'm able to use `processing` tools like `buffer`, but with heavy layers I want to display a progress bar, users can easily see the treatment progression.

In documentation, there is [some words](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html) about it but when I run simples examples, QGIS systematicaly not responding and there isn't any progress bar. Note that this treatment works perfectly without this progress bar issue.

Here is my code :

```
import time
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QProgressBar
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *

# Progress bar
progressMessageBar = iface.messageBar().createMessage("Work in progress...")
progress = QProgressBar()
progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(progress)
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(progressMessageBar, Qgis.Info)

# Layer
vlayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
count = vlayer.featureCount()
features = vlayer.getFeatures()

# Progression loop
for i, feature in enumerate(features):    
    percent = i / float(count) * 100
    # My treatment
    processing.runAndLoadResults('native:buffer', {"INPUT": vlayer, "DISTANCE": 20, "OUTPUT": 'memory:buffer'})
    # Progression status
    iface.statusBarIface().showMessage("Processed {} %".format(int(percent)))
    progress.setValue(percent)

iface.statusBarIface().clearMessage()
```

Am I missing something ? Maybe something is wrong in my loop. I'm working with QGIS 3.10.1.

Comment: look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/312997/49538

Comment: I've seen this post before and i'm ok with this, i can display a percentage progression in the python console. But how can i assign this to a bar ? (like a classic `QgsMessageBar()`)

Comment: To see if I understand, the progress bar is not showing in the status bar, right?. Have you try adding `time.sleep(1)` like in the doc example, just to check.

Comment: That's it. No problem with the first message (Work in progress), but after nothing and QGIS freeze. It seems there is a bug with my loop (like if the treatment apply in all the layer for each feature).

Comment: In your code, it seems you are doing a loop for each feature in your layer, but you give your layer to the processing algorithm. Is-it corect? Are you sure you don't get duplicated layers? I will write a better anwser tomorrow.

Comment: That's it, my loop isn't correct because i repeat the treatment for each features. I think i need to iterate processing by features.

Comment: Yes, that's it. You made the answer I was going to write.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With researches, i made this acceptable answer, without any loop. I assign `QgsProcessingFeedback()` to `QProgressBar()` and get a dynamic progression bar when `processing` is running :

```
# Progression bar
qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
progressMessageBar = qgis.utils.iface.messageBar()
progressbar = QProgressBar()
progressMessageBar.pushWidget(progressbar)

# Processing feedback
def progress_changed(progress):
    #print(progress)
    progressbar.setValue(progress) 

f = QgsProcessingFeedback()
f.progressChanged.connect(progress_changed)

# Layer and processing
vlayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
processing.runAndLoadResults('native:buffer', {"INPUT": vlayer, "DISTANCE": 20, "OUTPUT": 'memory:buffer'}, feedback=f)

# Clear the message bar when done
qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
```

Thanks to all, you put me on the good track.