# Error when displaying progress bar

Tags: pyqgis, code-review, progress

My initial code read an image, apply a median filter to it, and save the smoothed image. It looked like this :

```
#Image reading
rasterpath = r"C:/Users/SIEXT5646/Desktop/Donnes/2018_gris.tif"
ds = gdal.Open(rasterpath)
band1 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

#Median filter computation :
im_med = ndimage.median_filter(band1,size=20)

#Export of smoothed image
```

However I am working with very large image (orthophotos of infrastructure, such as tunnels), so I would like to add a process bar to my code. I used the idea developed in the link here : [Displaying progress bar when using QGIS processing tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348556/displaying-progress-bar-when-using-qgis-processing-tool). So now my code looks like this now :

```
# Progression bar
qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().clearWidgets()
progressMessageBar = qgis.utils.iface.messageBar()
progressbar = QProgressBar()
progressMessageBar.pushWidget(progressbar)

# Processing feedback
def progress_changed(progress):
#print(progress)
progressbar.setValue(progress)

f = QgsProcessingFeedback()
f.progressChanged.connect(progress_changed)

#Read image

#Median filter computation, with the addition require for the feedback
processing.runAndLoadResults(im_med = ndimage.median_filter(band1,size=20), feedback=f)

#Export smoothed image
```

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: runAndLoadResults() got an unexpected keyword argument 'im_med'`, so I'm guessing the problem is coming from the fact that I define a new variable Inside the processing.runAndLoadResults.

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: `runAndLoadResult` method takes the name of the algorithm to execute as its first parameter which should be a string. Please review [Using processing algorithms](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html)

Comment: Thk for your answer. If i understand well, following the principle describe in your link, I must re-write completely my code in order to add a progress bar ? I was hoping it would be quite an easy task :(

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz what's worrying me is that the function ndimage.median_filter is not a native function of QGIS, so even if I re-write all my script, in the part def processAlgorithm, I won't be able to call it..

Comment: The problem is  that `ndimage.median_filter` doesn't give you any feedback, because it's not a QGIS function. So you cannot use `ndimage.median_filter` with progressbar.

Comment: Well that's too bad, but alright ! At least I'm not going to spend more time on this. Can you write this as an answer, so I can accept it ?